# How to concatenate submatrix into a bigger matrix in Octave

Tags: arrays, matlab, image-processing, octave

I'm trying to solve the following issue: I have an 3x3x4 array like this:

```
A(:,:,1) =         A(:,:,2) =         A(:,:,3) =         A(:,:,4) =
  1 1 1              2 2 2              3 3 3              4 4 4
  1 1 1              2 2 2              3 3 3              4 4 4
  1 1 1              2 2 2              3 3 3              4 4 4
```

I would like to produce a 6x6 matrix like the following:

```
B = 
  1 1 1 3 3 3
  1 1 1 3 3 3
  1 1 1 3 3 3
  2 2 2 4 4 4
  2 2 2 4 4 4
  2 2 2 4 4 4
```

My first thought was to use something like the reshape function, but since it operates columnwise, the result is not what I want.

Do you have any ideas to perform it efficiently?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is for a general case of converting a `3D` array into such a `2D` array -

```
m = 2; %// number of 3D slices to be vertically concatenated to form the rows

m1 = size(A,1)*m;
m2 = size(A,3)/m;

B = reshape(permute(reshape(permute(A,[1 3 2]),m1,m2,[]),[1 3 2]),m1,[])
```

Sample run -

```
A(:,:,1) =
     1     1     7
     1     9     1
     1     7     2
A(:,:,2) =
     3     9     2
     9     4     7
     9     3     7
A(:,:,3) =
     2     6     8
     4     8     4
     1     8     4
A(:,:,4) =
     1     1     7
     8     3     4
     1     9     8
A(:,:,5) =
     7     9     2
     6     8     5
     4     1     6
A(:,:,6) =
     3     2     8
     4     9     1
     4     4     4
B =
     1     1     7     2     6     8     7     9     2
     1     9     1     4     8     4     6     8     5
     1     7     2     1     8     4     4     1     6
     3     9     2     1     1     7     3     2     8
     9     4     7     8     3     4     4     9     1
     9     3     7     1     9     8     4     4     4
```

Comment: Nice one! +1 from me haha I won't bother modifying my answer :)

Comment: @Benoit_11 Thanks!! Well these multi-dimensional arrays are a bit tricky, as you can see! :)

Answer (score 2):

Since your sub-matrices are all of the same size you can assign them directly into B:

```
clear

B = zeros(6);

A(:,:,1) = ones(3);
A(:,:,2) = 2*ones(3);
A(:,:,3) = 3*ones(3);
A(:,:,4) = 4*ones(3);

B = [A(:,:,1) A(:,:,3); A(:,:,2) A(:,:,4)]

B =

     1     1     1     3     3     3
     1     1     1     3     3     3
     1     1     1     3     3     3
     2     2     2     4     4     4
     2     2     2     4     4     4
     2     2     2     4     4     4
```

This might prove cumbersome if you have many more sub-matrices though but that could be automated.

Comment: thanks for the answer! If I'm not asking too much, could you please indicate how this could be automated for an arbitrary number of matrices?

Comment: You're welcome! For the general case please see @Divakar's answer; it's right on spot as usual.

Answer (score 1):

`permute` is much more efficient (à la Divakar) or manually slicing into a 2D array (à la Benoit), but I'll add something to the mix for future readers.  One way I can suggest is to take each plane and place it into a 1D cell array, reshape the cell array into a 2 x 2 grid, then convert the 2 x 2 grid into a final matrix.  Something like:

```
B = arrayfun(@(x) A(:,:,x), 1:4, 'uni', 0);
B = reshape(B, 2, 2);
B = cell2mat(B)

B =

     1     1     1     3     3     3
     1     1     1     3     3     3
     1     1     1     3     3     3
     2     2     2     4     4     4
     2     2     2     4     4     4
     2     2     2     4     4     4
```